# socket programming. c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

how can i make a program which can do messaging..... if i send a message it is recived by the user and the user reply reaches me..

Comment: As it stands this question is *very* general. Something more specific will allow more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, it's from application communicating with java-coded second one:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    public class TcpCommunication
        {
            private TcpListener commListener;
            private TcpClient client;
            private StreamReader reader;

            public TcpCommunication(int port)
            {
                this.commListener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}),port);
            }

            public bool isAlive()
            {
                return client != null && this.client.Connected;
            }

            public void waitForClient()
            {
                this.commListener.Start();
                this.client = commListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                this.reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                this.commListener.Stop();
            }

            public String getStringLine()
            {
                return reader.ReadLine();
            }

            public void writeStringLine(String commString)
            {
                commString = commString.Replace('\n','\t');

                NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(); 
                Byte[] stringInByteFormat = encoding.GetBytes(commString + "\n");                   networkStream.Write(stringInByteFormat,0,stringInByteFormat.Length);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approches to do so.

- You can use sockets (`System.Net.Sockets` namespace, start looking at classes `TcpClient` and `TcpListener`). This is a very low level approach, where you have to do everything by yourself.
- You can use one of the existing abstraction layers of communication programming like Webservices or WCF which i would recommend. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296040/25727) for places to start reading.

Answer (score 0):

You will find lots of good starting points if you search SO for questions about chat programs, as they are a great example of using sockets for peer-to-peer communications and they are interactive so you can experiment with them directly. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582097/java-chat-application

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use WCF (Windows communication Foundation)  and just use the net.tcp binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd943056.aspx

Basically, instead of having to create and marshal messages across sockets, you create a WCF service (which in code is just and interface and it's implementation with a few attributes) Then in the configuration file you tell it to listen on a tcp socket instead of http.

You can also configure it to work in duplex mode - which is two way mode.